# Geofence is not triggering without wifi

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

With the help of [link1](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) and [link2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing), I've successfully created poc for geofencing. Everything was fine with/without wifi(GPS is always enabled on app launch) untill one day I found "unfortunately google play services has stopped".

So I tried to force stop, clear cache and also now clear data of Google Play Services. Then after geofence is not triggering without wifi. I've also tried increasing radius up to 1000m, but no success. Location is the very same building of my office and yes I've also tried with going out in open sky.

And now twist is that a very same implementation is working on other devices. So I'm very sure that it has to do with force stop of google play services. Solution I want is to restart the google play services or is there any other reason behind this.

- Device : Samsung Galaxy Grand Quattro(GT-I8552)
- Andriod Version : 4.1.2
- Google Play Services : 7.5.74(1997312-034)
- Google Play Store : 5.6.8

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have cleared the data of Google Play Services as registered geofences are kept in the com.google.process.location process owned by the com.google.android.gms package. Now your app must re-register geofences. Please remember that the system restores geofences even if the Google Play Services is killed+restarted/upgraded but not if you clear its data. The same is also mentioned in the [link1](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) that you referenced under the section "Re-register geofences only when required"